# Is it good to use exception handling in this case?

Tags: javascript, exception

I am using this kind of code in JavaScript.

```
if(typeof a[x] != "undefined" && typeof a[x][y] != "undefined" && typeof a[x][y][z] != "undefined") {
    a[x][y][z].update();
}
// else do nothing
```

I just thought that using try catch to implement the above logic would simplify the code and reduce the checking of three conditions each time. (See below)

```
try {
    a[x][y][z].update();
} catch(e) {
}
```

Is it good to use try catch in such a situation?

Note: If you are wondering why I am checking the three conditions: a[][][] contains references to objects and the references are added dynamically.

Comment: The `try` method will also `catch` when there are other errors so I wouldn't use it.

Comment: @pimvdb: ??? what other errors do you mean?

Comment: @Kooilnc: Like errors happening within the `.update()` function. I don't know what that function is actually doing, but the `try/catch` suppresses *all* errors occuring in that line of code or other functions that are called there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Readability matters more, unless you're in an extremely performance optimized loop or function, it shouldn't make a difference.

As PleaseStand stated, wrapping the whole thing in a `try/catch` will hide any errors. You could alternatively do something like this, if you still wanted to `try/catch`

```
var fn = null;

try {
    fn = a[x][y][z].update;
} catch (e) {
    fn = function(){}
}

fn();
```

or

```
var fn = null;

try {
    fn = a[x][y][z].update;
} catch (e) {}

fn && fn();
```

Answer (score 1):

Any exception thrown by the `.update()` method is silently ignored, possibly hiding bugs. Note that in your original example, you don't have to use `typeof`:

```
if(a[x] !== undefined && a[x][y] !== undefined && a[x][y][z] !== undefined) {
    a[x][y][z].update();
}
```

Comment: +1 Note though that `undefined` could be set to some other value, so the `typeof` is more reliable.

Comment: Oh, I did not know this. For normal variables !== undefined does not work but it works for arrays. Why so?

Comment: @pimvdb I did not understand what you mean by setting undefined to some other value. undefined = 123???

Comment: Try it for yourself: `undefined = 123; var foo = undefined;`. Now `foo === undefined` but `typeof foo !== 'undefined'`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it good to use try catch in such a situation?

No, as it will catch and discard any other errors than the one you were expecting, making debugging much harder. Unfortunately JavaScript's exception handling is rather weak and gives you no ability to catch only certain exceptions. Instead, you have to catch everything, deliberately sniff for what you want, and re-throw the rest:

```
try {
    a[x][y][z].update();
} catch(e) {
    if (!(e instanceof TypeError))
        throw e;
}
```

which isn't very clear, and will still catch quite a lot of other potential errors since JavaScript's built-in exceptions like `TypeError` are pretty broad.

I would go for your original solution, except using the more explicit `in` operator instead of the clunky `typeof` test:

```
if (x in a && y in a[x] && z in a[x][y])
    a[x][y][z].update();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why the explicit check for undefined?

```
if(a[x] && a[x][y] && a[x][y][z]) {
    a[x][y][z].update();
}
```

Comment: @Cronco. I fail to see in which scenarios the intermediate values are falsy and yet a[x][y][z].update() be runnable. Any examples?

Comment: I can't think of any examples on the spot, but surely, computing something might at some point need 0 as an input.

Comment: @Cronco. 0 is a valid output in general, of course, but here you'd be doing 0[something] or 0.update()

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is pretty fault tollerant when it comes to handling *falsy* values, you could do something like:

```
var v = 
    (a ? (a[x] 
           ? (a[x][y] 
               ? (a[x][y][z] 
                   ? a[x][y][z] : null) 
               : null) 
           : null) 
    : null);

if (v) v.update();
```